# Unable to pass derived object from Python to Java in Py4J through a java method when base object is expected as parameter

Tags: py4j

I have a base class A and its derived class B. I have a Java method which takes object of Base class A. When I call that method from Py4J by passing derived class object, Py4J throws

> Method does not exist exception at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)

I have tried setting auto_convert to true, still the issue is same
I am using `py4j0.10.8.1.jar`

Is that limitation from Py4J?

Please help with this as we are trying to adopt Py4J for Python to Java interaction and I am stuck with it right now.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?